# click button action in sequentially order in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

created 4x4 metrics button in UITableView.
I want to select the button in sequentially order.

// button Creation in cell for row Index

```
for (int i = 0; i< [buttonArray count]; i++)
{
    int buttonSpace = 10 * i + 10;
    NSLog(@"ButtonPosition:%d",buttonSpace + (i * 50));
    cell.Button = [[CustomButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(buttonSpace + (i * 50),35, 50, 50)];
    cell.Button.layer.cornerRadius = 25;
    [cell.Button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.Button.buttonIndex = i;

    [cell.ScrollView addSubview:cell.Button];
    cell.ScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.3];
}
    rowIndexValue = indexPath.row;
```

// Button action in view controller.

```
-(void)buttonAction:(CustomButton *)sender
{
    if (rowIndexValue) {

        int counter = (int)[sender buttonIndex];
            if (counter == incrementValue)
            {
                sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
                counter += 1;
                incrementValue = counter;
            }
            else{
                sender.selected = NO;
            }
        }
}
```

The order of button action in sequential order, for any random row's.
user select 3rd row but selection row in third row start from 1st button then 2nd button then 3rd button finally 4th button.

4x4 - > 4 row for UITableview 4 button in each row. Once button is click it will be in disable Mode

Comment: What is the issue exactly?

Comment: @Lion I want to select the button's in sequencally  in any random UITableView row.  4x4 4 row forUITableview 4 button in each row. Once button is click it will be in disable Mode.

Comment: `the button's in sequencally in any random UITableView row` what do you mean by this line?

Answer (score 0):

Set proper value so that you can recognise button column as well as row position. buttonIndex is just saving i value so you will only get column position.You may set button.tag=indexPath.row and use it in the buttonAction method to know the row position.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `NSInteger` tagValue globally in your viewController.

```
-(NSUInteger)getRowByBtn:(UIButton *)btn :(UITableView *)tblView
{
    CGPoint center= btn.center;
    CGPoint rootViewPoint = [btn.superview convertPoint:center toView:tblView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tblView indexPathForRowAtPoint:rootViewPoint];
    NSLog(@"indexPath = %ld", (long)indexPath.row);
    return indexPath.row;
}
```

With the help of above method you can get `indexpath.row` value from which you can determine the button for each row in the tableview.

```
[cell.Button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)buttonAction:(UIButton*)sender
{     
    UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;
    tagValue = [self getRowByBtn:btn :yourTableview];
    [[self.view viewWithTag:tagValue]setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    //or any other action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set UIButton tag in `CellForRowAtIndexPath` 
Like this :

```
 [cell.btn_name addTarget:self action:@selector(onclick_button:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 self.btn_name.tag=indexpath.row;
```

And

```
-(IBAction)onclick_button:(id)sender
{
    int btn_index= ((UIView*)sender).tag;
    NSLog(@"Btn index:%d",btn_index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It fix the problem with below code.

```
-(void)buttonAction:(UIButton*)sender{
    CGPoint center = sender.center;
        CGPoint rootViewPoint = [sender.superview convertPoint:centre toView:self.tableView];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:rootViewPoint];
        sender.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        CustomButton *enableNextButton = (CustomButton *) [[self.goalsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] viewWithTag:sender.tag+1];
        enableNextButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
```